# Preventing div from going outside the page

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

My current situation:

I've got a very simple css3 tooltip-menu, which is hidden by default and shown on mouseover. It has a fixed width and absolute right positioning (with an arrow in the middle pointing on the hovered element). My problem is that on the smaller windows, after hovering the element the horizontal scrollbar is created. How to prevent it? How to make the menu box appear on the left side in that situation?

The code for my current menu is simple:

```
<ul><li>Hover me 
<ul><li>Hovered element</li>
<li>Hovered element 2</li></ul>
</ul>
```

And the css is something like that:

```
ul > li > ul {display:none}
ul > li:hover > ul {display:block}
```

with, of course, some other styling. Is there any jquery script on css trick to do that?

Comment: You have to measure the mouse position and set the tooltip position accordingly - JQuery can do this as can vanilla JS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly you have to work with `Media Queries`. So you have to get the size of the screen, when this behavior is happening. And change the settings.

Something like this:

your normal css defintion :

```
.reframe {
 //Your Settings
}


@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    .reframe { //your new settings }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use that particular method. Seems the most fluid.

Comment: @PawełRyszka u are welcome, but i dont know why i got a downvote lol

Comment: I have no idea, I can't vote down / up yet, but I've accepted this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Finally got a PURE CSS answer. You can use `word-wrap` property to help you out. This is the updated CSS:

```
ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
    margin-left:-15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
    display:block;
}
```

Working Example:http://jsfiddle.net/p7wzv57j/

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar situation. In my situation, the messages were created using JavaScript, so at the time of creation, I used the element's `offset` to see how far it was from the right edge of the screen, then gave it a different class (different styling) accordingly.

Without JavaScript, I think the best you could get is to use media queries, and do blanket changes to all of them. Maybe it would be helpful to have a `.left` and a `.right` version and you could set that explicitly.